# How to correct child scope (ng-include) issue inside controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form like below where i am loading an external template (sample.html) using ng-include ,

```
<div>
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-include src="'/src/sample.html'"></form>   
</div>
<div>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()" translate>global.save</button>
</div>
```

My sample.html has few input fields. I have the same controller for both these files and i am loading the data for these files in that like below,

```
Restangular.one('fromAPIdata',id).get().then(function(data){
        $scope.formData=data;
    });
```

**Now when i print $scope.formData in my form it is the same but when i print the same in sample.html most of the data are missing**.

**EDIT** : 
And i came across an article about scope issues, that ng-include creates a new scope, 
[StackOverflow Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

The problem solved when i used **$parent.formData** in my external template.

**Is it possible to solve it in the controller instead of the template file.**
Any help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see more of your code? ngInclude creates a child scope so it's possible some of the fields are bounded to properties on the child scope and not the parent scope.

Comment: Yes you are correct , can i correct this scope issue in my controller? @AnthonyChu

Comment: Need to see more of your code to understand what's happening.